# Saving one measurement one display and recalling it using Arduino

Tags: arduino, measurement, lcd, button

I am using an Arduino with 49E Hall sensors and a 16x2 LCD display and buttons. If I push the button, I want to display the current measurement of the hall sensor (one number). And if I push the button again, I want to display the new current measurement of the hall sensor.

The only thing I could find on the internet is to send the measurement to a drive and recall that. However, I could not find how to save one measurement and I think it could be done much easier. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: [Variables.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science))   I'm sure you used some in the program you wrote to display values on the LCD.

Comment: So, the display should stop updating when button is pushed, and start upadting when pushed again? Start/stop button?

Comment: yess exactly! @Justme

Comment: I think this is purely a simple software writing question, not electronics design. So, what have you tried so far and where are you stuck? Can you toggle a run/stop mode variable when detecting a button push? Can you choose to update display based on that run/stop mode state?

Comment: @Justme I tried that with a delay, but then the whole arduino stops with his code, so that did not work out. I also tried it with saving data to a file, but then I could not get only one measurement...